# Primefaces3 update contextmenu tree

Tags: tree, primefaces, contextmenu

Is there any idea that updating the ContextMenu everytime I click a different tree item?

I mean I would like to update the ContextMenu dynamically, for example, when I right click
the root of the tree, the menu options could be "menu item 1", "menu item 2" and 
"menu item 3".
However, if I right click the leaf of the tree, the menu options could be "menu item 4", "menu item 5" and "menu item 6".

I tried several different way, but none of them can work as my expectation.

Please give me some help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From the Primefaces documentation (http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html) page 446:

> **ContextMenu** 
>   Tree has special integration with context menu, you can
>   even match different context menus with different tree nodes using
>   nodeType option of context menu that matches the tree node type.

Sounds like they have exactly what you are looking for. All you need to do is create the various menus you want and set "nodeType" attribute.